# Can we write multiple css style in single line in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Can we write multiple css style in single line in JQuery

```
       $('.ui-dialog').css("left","475px");
       $('.ui-dialog').css("top","215px");
```

Does we can write this to single line like below

```
       $('.ui-dialog').css("'left','475px'","'top','215px'"); // Test
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass an object with the key as the property and the value as what you may expect.

```
$('.ui-dialog').css({
  left: 475,
  top: 215
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. The jQuery .css() method also accepts a map. Check their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more examples.

```
$('.ui-dialog').css({
    'left' : '475px', 
    'top' : '215px'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also chain `css` calls together:

```
$(".ui-dialog").css("left", "475px").css("top", "215px");
```